# If Jehovah's Witnesses believe they should use Jehovah to be accurate why don't they use Jesus' real Hebrew name?

Tags: jehovahs-witnesses, names-of-god, name-of-jesus, hebrew

I think everyone knows that the name Jesus is Greek, but why don’t Jehovah’s Witnesses use his Hebrew name, which is closer to *Joshua* than to *Jesus*?

Comment: Closer perhaps, but arguably not exactly identical. So if both are approximations, why choose one over the other?

Comment: Given they are close in Hebrew their English and other modern language forms vary significantly more, to the point they do not appear related.

Comment: See also: [Jesus and Mary / Joshua and Miriam](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/2229) and [Is God's name Yahweh or Jehovah?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1630)

Comment: "Jesus" is not Greek--it's English.  The Greek is more like "Iesous".  The name "Jesus" is derived from that Greek word.

Comment: Also for JWs, Jehovah and Jesus are not on the same "level", so to speak, because they do not believe in trinity. So while Jehovah is the name of God (and was actually in common use in Europe and elsewhere long before JWs), Jesus is a being created by God (as the bible refers to him as the "first born of all creation" in [Col. 1:15](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=colossians+1%3A15&version=KJV)). For this reason JWs would not direct worship to Jesus (or Mary, or the "saints", for that matter) nor pray directly to Jesus, being that prayer is a form of worship.

Answer (score 29):

There's a problem with one of your assumptions: Jehovah's Witnesses don't use *Jehovah* "to be accurate". They use *Jehovah* because they think it's important to call God by name, and because *Jehovah* is the traditional rendering in English. They accept that the original pronunciation has been lost, and argue that were it important, Jehovah God would not have allowed it to be lost. They do make linguistic arguments in favour of a trisyllabic pronunciation, but these are lesser considerations.

They also remark that many names contain elements of the divine name: *Jeremiah* and *Jehoshaphat*, for example. They argue that if you were to change *Jehovah* to *Yahweh*, you should, for the sake of consistency, change these names too.

For more information, see their official publication [*The Divine Name That Will Endure Forever*](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/library/r1/lp-e/all-publications/brochures-and-booklets/divine-name-na).

Comment: "They use Jehovah because they think it's important to call God by name". Do you happen to know why they think that? Some Christians don't do that out of respect (Just as you wouldn't dare call the president by name). What is their reason for believing the opposite?

Comment: Basically, because the name is used in the Bible, and it is nowhere said not to use it.

Comment: God want's us to know his name. There are quite a few instances in the bibles that tell us that, such as Psalm 83:18 "May people know that you, whose name is Jehovah,
You alone are the Most High over all the earth." Man decided that God's name was too holy to be said. If that where the case would God have given us his name? No, then clearly this thought of not using his name out of respect is from man.

Comment: "They also remark that many names contain elements of the divine name: Jeremiah and Jehoshaphat, for example." And same can be said if the divine name were Yahweh, regarding names such as Abiyah, Adoniyah, etc., and these also occurse at the end of many names, including Elijah (i.e., Eliyah). But you did answer the question asked. :)

Comment: The publication you mention is not available online, but the excerpt on "Jehovah" from *Insight*, which makes many of the same points, is [available here](http://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200002391).

Comment: @MonikaMichael, as to "Just as you wouldn't dare call the president by name"...based on what logic? People have been calling Donald J Trump and all previous presidents by their names (and worse) since the declaration of independence.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude The publication is now available on jw.org. I've edited in a link to it.

Comment: @4castle that link does not take me to the divine name brochure perhaps linking to revised NWT appendix would be better?

Comment: @Kris Hmm, the link must have moved. Is it working now that I updated it?

Comment: @4castle  yess that fixed it

Answer (score 4):

The actual pronunciation of the tetragrammaton is up for debate.  If a person leaned toward "Yahweh" or "Yehovah," we wouldn't have a problem with that.  But "Jehovah" is the most accepted version in English, and a viable translation.

Jesus is an acceptable English translation OF the greek version (Iesous) of a name that would more directly be transliterated Yeshua (which would be directly translated "Joshua").  Most of us recognize that and would have no problem with a more original pronunciation.  But most of the biblical names translated into modern versions had a different original pronunciation... the point is that we recognize which individual is which.

No, we do not believe in a trinity and do not believe Jesus is a "person of a Godhead."  But Jesus is still our lord and savior, the son of God, our messiah and king.  We believe everything he said about himself, including what he said at John 14:28 and 17:3.

Answer (score 3):

This is my understanding from studying with a JW who visited my home and became a weekly visitor over the course of several months. (I am not JW, but am not opposed to study.) During the course of this study, I was informed that they (JW) do not believe in the trinity. They are not concerned with honoring Jesus in the same way that God should be honored.

(Also, the correct name for Jesus, according to Jewish tradition is Yeshua.)

Answer (score 3):

The question is answered well in the 2013 edition of the New World Translation [appendix](https://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/study-bible/appendix-a/tetragrammaton-divine-name/):

Much info on why Jehovah’s witnesses believe using the name Jehovah is important is found there.
Specific to your question is the following:

> Those who say that the divine name should not be used because it is not known exactly how to pronounce it will nevertheless freely use the name Jesus. However, Jesus’ first-century disciples said his name quite differently from the way most Christians do today. To Jewish Christians, the name Jesus was probably pronounced Ye·shuʹa‛. And the title “Christ” was Ma·shiʹach, or “Messiah.” Greek-speaking Christians called him I·e·sousʹ Khri·stosʹ, and Latin-speaking Christians Ieʹsus Chriʹstus. Under inspiration, the Greek translation of his name was recorded in the Bible, showing that first-century Christians followed the sensible course of using the form of the name common in their language. Similarly, the New World Bible Translation Committee feels that it is reasonable to use the form “Jehovah,” even though that rendering is not exactly the way the divine name would have been pronounced in ancient Hebrew.

Another great question comes to mind when looking at the picture below

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Its the same reason why Jehovah's Witnesses use Jehovah which is not Hebrew or Greek.

What matter most is that you are using the accepted equivalent translation in your own language or dialect to pertain to God or to his son, Jesus, and you are not constraint of using their names because of their original pronunciation is lost through time.

Answer (score 0):

You used "Jehovah" when if to use it closer to Hebrew then it Would be Yahweh.

**You say why don't  JWs use the Hebrew for Jesus when you yourself use the English for God's name instead of the Hebrew yourself; why because that the natural way in our language.**

We use the language **common** to the people in the land we live in.  If I lived in Israel the I would use Hebrew, or in Greece I would use Greek but in England (USA) we the English version.  Examples of Jesus' name in various languages:-

Afrikaans   Jesus

Albanian    Jezusi

Arabic  `Isà عيسى‎ (Islamic or classical arabic) / Yasū` يسوع‎ (Christian or latter Arabic)

Amharic ኢየሱስ

Aragonese   Chesús

Aramaic/Syriac  ܝܫܘܥ (Isho)

Arberesh    Isuthi
Armenian    Հիսուս (Eastern Armenian) Յիսուս (Western Armenian) (Hisus)

Azerbaijani İsa

Belarusian  Ісус (Isus) (Orthodox) / Езус (Yezus) (Catholic)

Bengali যীশু (Jeeshu/Zeeshu) (Christian) 'ঈসা ('Eesa) (General)

Breton  Jezuz

Catalan Jesús
Chinese simplified Chinese: 耶稣; traditional Chinese: 耶穌; pinyin: Yēsū

Cornish Yesu

Croatian    Isus

Czech   Ježíš

Dutch   Jezus

Estonian    Jeesus

Filipino    Jesús (Christian and secular) / Hesús or Hesukristo (religious)

Fijian  Jisu

Finnish Jeesus

French  Jésus

Galician    Xesús

Garo    Jisu

Georgian    იესო (Ieso)

Ghanaian    Yesu

Greek   Ιησούς (Iisús modern Greek pronunciation)

Haitian Creole  Jezi

Hausa   Yesu

Hawaiian    Jesu

Hebrew  Yeshua יֵשׁוּעַ‎

Hindustani  ईसा / عيسى (īsā)

Hmong Daw   Yexus

Hungarian   Jézus

Icelandic   Jesús

Igbo    Jisos

Indonesia   Yesus (Christian) / Isa (Islamic)

Irish   Íosa

Italian Gesù

Japanese    イエス (Iesu)/イエズス (Iezusu)(Catholic)/ゼス(zesu) ゼズス(zezusu)
(Kirishitan)イイスス(Iisusu)(Eastern Orthodox)

Jinghpaw    Yesu

Kazakh  Иса (Isa)

Khmer   យេស៑ូវ (Yesu)

Kisii   Yeso

Korean  예수 (Yesu)

Kurdish Îsa

Latvian Jēzus

Ligurian    Gesû

Limburgish  Zjezus

Lithuanian  Jėzus

Lombard Gesü

Luganda Yesu

मराठी-Marathi   येशू - Yeshu

Malagasy    Jeso, Jesoa, Jesosy

Malayalam   ഈശോ (Isho), യേശു (Yeshu)

Mirandese   Jasus

Maltese Ġesù

Mongolian   Есүс

Neapolitan  Giesù

Norman  Jésus

Occitan Jèsus

Piedmontese Gesù

Polish  Jezus

Portuguese  Jesus

Romanian    Isus (almost all) / Iisus (Eastern Orthodox)

Russian Иисус (Iisus)

Sardinian   Gesùs

Serbian Isus / Исус

Sicilian    Gesù

Sinhala ජේසුස් වහන්සේ - Jesus Wahanse

Scottish Gaelic Ìosa

Slovak  Ježiš

Slovenian   Jezus

Spanish Jesús

Swahili Yesu

Sylheti যীশু (Zishu) (Christian) 'ঈছা ('Eesa) (General)

Tajik   Исо (Iso)

Tamil   இயேசு - Yesu

Telugu  Yesu

Thai    เยซู - "Yesu"

Turkish İsa

Turkmen Isa

Ukrainian   Ісус (Isus)

Urdu    عیسیٰ

Uzbek   Iso

Venetian    Jesu

Vietnamese  Giêsu, Dêsu

Welsh   Iesu

Yoruba  Jesu

Zulu    uJesu

Comment: This is not an answer to the question posted

Comment: @Kris 22 Is this better?

Comment: Your first sentence makes no sense.

Comment: @curiousdannii Better in the above?